# Gateway computer doesn't provide enough room to add a new harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, sata, computer-building, desktop-computer

I opened my Gateway PC (**Gateway DX4860-EF22P**) to add a hard drive, but I was surprised to discover that the manufacturer did not provide enough room to put the new hard drive.

As you can see in the image, it is blocked by the right edge of the tower's frame. This frame cannot be removed and the box holding the first hard drive can't be removed without completely disassembling the whole tower.

[image: Gateway hard drive no room]

Has anyone ever encountered something like this before?? What did you do?

Comment: The exact model of the given computer would help quite a bit in identifying a solution for you. I'm pretty sure you not the only one scratching his head on this.

Comment: This is a very strange location for the HDD - are the cables supposed to be bent? I guess you will have to disassemble the whole tower though.

Comment: @Marc-AndreR. Added model number. Gateway DX4860-EF22P

Comment: I know you said that you can not remove the HDD-cage. However, I had a very similar case once and after some fiddling, I could somewhat remove this HDD-cage without completely disassembling everything. Maybe after you remove the front-plate of your case?

Comment: @Slizzered Removing the front-plate doesn't do anything, since there's a metal wll behind it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!!

The hard drive casing can be pulled forward about an inch, and then released with pressure down and to the left. Now I have the box pulled out.

NOTE: In the image above, I already removed a screw in the metal face just above the case. You see the hole in the top center of image.

Answer (score 0):

put it under DVD driver, you can find holder for your HDD in computer store i have the same case, or you can remove it and rotate

Answer (score 0):

How about a 2.5 inch hard drive instead of a 3.5 drive? Cables with 90 degree connectors would work for power and data. Vent holes along the bay could be used for mounting screws, or just cobble something up for mounting if you're inventive.